# Assert.ThrowsException test fails when it does throw exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visualstudio.testtools

I'm using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` for unit testing.

I have this test which asserts that an exception was thrown and it is failing

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ShouldThrowHttpExceptionIfPassedObjectIsNull()
{
    _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<DataService>>();

    // setup memoryCache
    object expected = null;
    _mockNullMemoryCache = MockMemoryCacheService.GetNullMemoryCache(expected);
    _mockSessionManagementService = new MockSessionManagementService();

    _ds = new DataService(
        _mockLogger.Object,
        _mockNullMemoryCache.Object,
        _mockSessionManagementService
    );
    Assert.ThrowsException<HttpException>(() => _ds.RetrieveFileData<object>(_incorrectFilePath, false));
}
```

When I debug it, the last line of code to run before it errors out and fails is this:

[image]

The exception `ex` is a `system.invalidOperationException` but that shouldn't matter because it throws an HttpException not matter what. Why is the test failing with the reason:

> Test Name:    ShouldThrowHttpExceptionIfPassedObjectIsNull Test
>   FullName: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ShouldThrowHttpExceptionIfPassedObjectIsNull
>   Test
>   Source:   C:\Users\xxx\xxx.cs
>   : line 88 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:04:35.5251661
>
> Result StackTrace:     at
>   xxxxxx.d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx.cs:line
>   101
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) Result Message: Assert.ThrowsException failed. No exception
>   thrown. HttpException exception was expected.

**EDIT**
The code then moves into this code block after the image:

```
else
                {
                    // Parsing issue
                    _logger.LogError(string.Format("Id={0}, Could not retrieve data from {1} : Malformed source data", _sessionManagementService.SessionId, url));
                    throw new HttpException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Malformed source data", true);
                }
```

As it is throwing the HttpException above, it throws a DllNotFoundException.

> Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'combase.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

Comment: @ThomasWeller no but the test is testing for HttpException, which is the one that is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at the type hierarchy of [HttpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx), I see that it doe not inherit from InvalidOperationException. Therefore the unit test fails correctly.

Likely there's some LINQ code or other code which cannot execute correctly, therefore catches the HttpException and converts it into the InvalidOperationException.

You should be able to debug the unit test. Instruct Visual Studio to stop at exceptions, then go forward step by step and try to find out where your exception gets converted, e.g. when you step through some LINQ code.

The MoveNext() call indicates that something tries to loop over values. When debugging, disable [Just my code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx), because it could be in the .NET framework.

Comment: But when I go forward step by step from the line of code in the image above, it just crashes after that line of code.

Comment: Okay disregard my last comment. Doing that now. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is the solution. Thanks!. I'm just wondering if you could point me in the right direction regarding what I found out (see the edit in the bottom of my question). It's strange because it throws the HttpException successfully the first time, although it has only 2 argument compared to 3 arguments in the last one. Maybe the code under test needs to be changed?

Comment: A DllNotFoundException is something different again. Can you go on debugging? Is DllNotFoundException caught by something else once more?

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I forgot that _logger is mocked. I just need to keep working on this in solitude as you have help all you can from across the interwebs. Thanks for your help!